# android-ImageView in listview not showing image when scroll up and down

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm getting images from the internet via universalImageDownloader and I'm using ViewHolder for showing them :

```
public class ListAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    public ListAdapter2(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity = getActivity();
        this.list = list;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> geting(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        if (this.list == null) {
            this.list = result;
        } else {
            this.list.addAll(result);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grids, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        item = list.get(position);

        if(item.get("img").length()>0)
            imageLoader.displayImage("http://website.com/img/" + item.get("img"), holder.img, options,
                imageListener);
        else
            holder.img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fix));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (this.list.size() > 0)
            this.list.clear();
    }
}

private static class ImageDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

    static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested it with 3 phones and it works fine but when I test it on my friends't phone, some times one of the images is not showing .

For example, when I come to activity , it shows all the images and when I scroll down where last items are not showing anymore and  then I scroll up, suddenly one of the images that's been showing before is not showing anymore and it shows the default image for it .

Is there anything wrong with this code ? 
By the way, I've 4 tabs and this happens in the tabs .

Thanks

Comment: for that you need to implement lazy loading of images. Or use piccaso library.

Comment: did displayImage() encode spaces to %20 ?

Answer (score 2):

the problem with the displayImage method, it could not encode URL properly some cases ..the better approch you should use Picasso library

if you are using android studio so add

> compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

in build.gradle file and sync:

or else [Picasso Site](http://square.github.io/picasso/) download Jar file for eclipse

after that you are able to use Picasso library and replace your lines with

```
if(item.get("img").length()>0)
        imageLoader.displayImage("http://website.com/img/" + item.get("img"), holder.img, options,
            imageListener);
    else
        holder.img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fix));
    }

 String imgUrl = "http://website.com/img/" + item.get("img");
    if (!imgUrl.equals(""))
        Picasso.with(activity).load(imgUrl).into(holder.img);
    else
        Picasso.with(activity).load(R.drawable.fix).into(holder.img );
```

Answer (score 0):

use "lazyImageLoaderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"
where lazyImageLoaderAdapter is the object of any adapter.